# Mysql permissions UPDATE error.

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a table from inside my code. I am modding an preexisting code in order to upload pdf document instead jpg. The auctions table has this features

```
mysql> describe webid_auctions;
+----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(32)           | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
...
| pict_url       | tinytext          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

and the filestore table has this

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| auction_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_action | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| filename    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mimetype    | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| url         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the code i am trying to execute is this:

```
  foreach ($UPLOADED_PICTURES as $k => $v)
            {
                $system->move_file($upload_path . session_id() . '/' . $v, $upload_path . $auction_id . '/' . $v);
                chmod($upload_path . $auction_id . '/' . $v, 0777);

                $furl = $upload_path . $auction_id . '/' . $v;
                $uid = $user->user_data['id'];
                /*first query */
                $query = "INSERT into " .$DBPrefix. "filestore SET
                    auction_id = '$auction_id',
                    user_id = '$uid',
                    user_action = 'hire',
                    filename = '$v',
                    url = '$furl'";
                $res = mysql_query($query);
                $system->check_mysql($res, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
                /*Second query */
                $query = "UPDATE " .$DBPrefix. "auctions SET
                    pict_url = '$v',
                    WHERE id = '$auction_id'";
                $res = mysql_query($query);
                $system->check_mysql($res, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);


                 }
```

The first query is performed with no problem. When the code execute the second query, 
php tells me

```
 ErrorArray ( [0] => Unknown error type: [2] fopen(/var/www/WeBid//logs/requests.log):
 failed to open stream: Permission denied on /var/www/WeBid/includes/functions_user.php 
 line 74 [1] => Database access error. Please contact the site administrator. UPDATE 
 webid_auctions SET pict_url = 'financialfoundamentals.pdf', WHERE id = '18' You have an 
 error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
 for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = '18'' at line 3 page:/var/www/WeBid/sell.php 
 line:235 [2] => Unknown error type: [2] fopen(/var/www/WeBid/logs/error.log): failed to 
 open stream: Permission denied on /var/www/WeBid/includes/errors.inc.php line 23 )
```

I am not en expert neither of php nor of mysql, but the csm act into the databse with a unique user with all permissions granted. I have checked the query from inside mysql and all work fine, so I can't understand where the error could came from.
Who can have an idea what is happening?

Comment: You need to create a connection to the MySQL DB. See this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extra comma `,` after `pict_url = '$v',`. Removing it should fix the problem.